# Debugging Godot game with Rider C#

Tags: c#, debugging, breakpoints, godot, rider

I've recently started using Godot and want to use Rider to debug my game. I have the Godot Support plugin in Rider for C#, and it seems to be working for the most part. I have the debug symbol in the top right that causes the app to launch in debug mode. However, breakpoints are not being hit/generated. When I hover over the breakpoint, this is what I see:
[image]

I've searched online and I've found almost nothing about this. The only two things that I found mentioning this were for Unity and were unsolved. Has anyone else experienced this?

I feel like it's likely something simple that I just overlooked. I'd appreciate anyone's help.

Comment: If this were Visual Studio, the first thing I might do is to do a Clean Build and then a Complete Rebuild. If the IDE guesses that the source and the Build aren't in sync, it can't create the breakpoint (in VS, anyway)

Comment: @Flydog57 Rider has that option too and I tried that. No luck.

Comment: Seems that even though pdb symbols were created, they were not loaded. And Rider (in contrast with VS) doesn't have a tool to show whether symbols were loaded for a specific dll or not, as here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-18260/implement-Modules-view-debugger-as-in-VS#focus=Comments-27-5251257.0-0 . If DLLs and PDB files are in different folders, you may try to copy pdbs to the same folder with dlls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After removing and reinstalling the Godot Support plugin, I discovered what my problem was. My configurations were incorrect. Somehow the first time I installed the Godot Support plugin it gave me the below configuration.
[image]
**Note:** The working directory wasn't actually set in the configuration at first. Not knowing where it needed to be set, I just set it to what you see above, which was very wrong now that I see what it was supposed to be.

After reinstalling the plugin, a new configuration was created that looked like this:
[image]

I am not sure how the first one got so screwed up, but after the reinstall, breakpoints are being hit.

Comment: It seems like a different type of configuration.